# XPath - Check if the button in 5th column of the last row of the table has specific text

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I am trying to write some automated front end tests using Selenium.

I'm currently attempting to select, as the title says, a button in the fifth column of the last row which has a button where the text of that button is 'XYZ'

I have a snippet to grab raw text from the columns and it works fine:

```
//tr[td[.='XYZ']][last()]/td[4]
```

I tried to change the td index in order to select the button's text - but I'm guessing it's not working because a button, unlike the previous `td` value, is not pure text. It contains markup so, the selection needs further specifying.

I then tried the following selection:

```
//tr[td[button[text()='XYZ']]][last()]/td[5]/button
```

Trying to select the last `tr` which has a `td` which has a `button` the text of which is 'XYZ, doesn't work.

**My Question**

Using XPath, how do I determine whether or not there is a button in the fifth column of the last row in the table, with the text 'XYZ'?

I have never worked with XPath, I'll be reading up on it in the meantime.

**Update**

Markup:

```
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">New verification code</button>
</td>
```

Error

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//tr[last()][td[5]/button[text()='XYZ']]"}

Comment: You are saying `it works fine` then `it's not working`. Please update the Question with relevant `HTML` along with your exact requirement & Code trials.

Comment: If you read it - I said it worked for a different selection, but not the one with the button in it - they're not referring to the same thing.

Comment: Please make clear what you want. You said you were looking for `button` within `td`. Now your example shows also `form`. Do you need to cover that as well in the XPath expression? Is it a condition or can it be ignored?

Comment: I didn't mention the form. It can be ignored, all I need is the button. Had I needed something else, I would have specified.I'm showing the extra markup in case it aids anyone in figuring something out.

Comment: The fact that it can be ignored is relevant. So you should have specified it. If your scenario is not transparent, it becomes difficult to help you. Anyway, I update the answer to ignore anything between `td` and `button`. If there is anything else, please tell us.

Comment: There's no form anymore in the markup.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that

```
//tr[last()]/td[5]//button[text()='XYZ']
```

is the right expression to get the button element.

In case you want to select the whole row containing that button it should read:

```
//tr[last()][td[5]//button[text()='XYZ']]
```

(edit: updated xpath to skip elements between `td` and `button`)

Comment: thanks for the comment - this doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Nothing changed.

Comment: Fixed. Xpath don't operate on 0-based indexes.